# How does scalding pass user functions to remote MapReduce nodes

Tags: java, scala, scalding

When working with Scalding, you have the ability to provide a function.  I was wondering how scalding passes these functions to the remote map/reduce tasks?  Is this using something in scala or something generic that can be done with anonymous objects?

Answer (score 3):

It's plain old Java serialization which is done by Cascading.

Comment: Thanks.  Was thinking that but was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It uses [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/), a java library upon Apache Hadoop.

Comment: How does cascading pass anonymous objects to map/reduce tasks?  I know how to do this if the task is given a Class and create it itself, but with an anonymous object it is not as clear.